# Voice messaging app with multiple recipients

Tags: audio, chat

I'm looking for a free tool, preferably something you can use with both mobile and computer.

I want to record and send voice messages to groups of people. It would be very good if there is no time limit for the recordings, and that you can organize them somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### **[Zello](http://www.zello.com/)**

It is a push-to-talk app that allows you to send voice messages to one or more contacts. You can organize your contacts in channels. Some of its features are:

- Create and join channels (can be private or public)
- Saves message history
- Works on Andriod, iOS, Blackberry, Windows Phone, and PC
- Ability to leave messages or carry "live" conversations

I couldn't find any information about the limit of message length, and I have only tested it for ones that are a few minutes long. I assume that there is no set limitation